# Is there a way to add 3 seconds to the CountDownTimer?

Tags: android, kotlin, timer, countdowntimer

Is there a way to add 3 seconds to the CountDownTimer when the user gets 3 answers correct (nonconsecutive) and when the timer is running? For an example if the user gets 3 answers correct when the timer displays 10 and it should increase to 13 seconds.
This is the code I've implemented and it doesn't work.

```
class GamePage : AppCompatActivity() {
    var correctCount = 0
    var wrongCount = 0
    val timer: TextView = findViewById(R.id.timer)
   

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_page)

        val finish = Intent(this, GameOver::class.java)
        var timeCount : Long = 50000

        fun counter(timeCount: Long){

            var countdownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(50000, 1000) {

            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                timer.text = "Seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000

            }

            @Override
            override fun onFinish() {
                if (correctCount !=0 && correctCount % 5 == 0) {
                    finish.putExtra("correct", correctCount.toString())
                finish.putExtra("wrong", wrongCount.toString())
                startActivity(finish)
                } else {
                    counter(5000);
                }

            }
        }.start();
        }
        counter(timeCount)
}
```

Comment: Cancel the countdownTimer and start it again with new values . Keep the remaining time in a global variable and add 3 seconds to it and start timer again .

Answer (score 0):

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
       //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mTextField.setText("done!");
    }

}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not coroutines?
You can easily modify the counter, and the timer will increase.

```
    fun counter (timeCount: Long) {
        var counter = timeCount
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            while (counter > 0) {
                delay(1000L)
                counter -= 1000
                if (isAnswerCorrect()) {
                    counter += 3 * 1000L     
                }
            }
            // timer finished
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a countdown Flow like this:

```
    fun countdownFlow(duration: Duration) = flow {
        val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + duration.inWholeMilliseconds
        while(isActive) {
            val timeRemaining = (endTime - System.currentTimeMillis()).coerceAtLeast(0L).milliseconds
            emit(timeRemaining)
            if (timeRemaining == Duration.ZERO) break
            delay(1)
        }
    }
```

And then use it like this, where you cancel your coroutine and restart it if you want to increase the timer.

```
class GamePage : AppCompatActivity() {
    var correctCount = 0
    var wrongCount = 0
    val timer: TextView = findViewById(R.id.timer)

    private var remainingTime = Duration.ZERO
    private var countdownJob: Job? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_page)
        startCountdown(50.seconds)
    }

    private fun startCountdown(duration: Duration)
        countdownJob?.cancel()
        remainingTime = duration
        countdownJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
            countdownFlow(duration).collect {
                remainingTime = it
                timer.text = "Seconds remaining: ${it.inWholeSeconds}"
            }
            
            if (correctCount !=0 && correctCount % 5 == 0) {
                val finish = Intent(GamePage.this, GameOver::class.java).apply {
                    putExtra("correct", correctCount.toString())
                    putExtra("wrong", wrongCount.toString())
                }
                startActivity(finish)
            } else {
                startCountdown(5.seconds)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun addTime(duration: Duration) {
        startCountdown(remainingTime.milliseconds + duration)
    }

}
```